# How to install PHP IMAP extension on Amazon Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: php, linux, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I've tried it with the container command:

```
install_php_imap:
    command: yum install php-imap
```

but I still get this error when I try to use it:

```
Call to undefined function imap_open()
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: did you restart the server after the install? use `phpinfo()` or `php -i` to check the install worked

Comment: Hi Dagon, yes i did but it doesn't work. If I run the yum command via ssh I get the error "php54-common conflicts with php-common-5.3.27-1.0.amzn1.x86_64" .. not sure what that means?

Comment: unfathomable as to why you wouldn't mention the error message when you first posted ...

Comment: Look at the version numbers in that message: it seems that Yum is trying to pull in PHP 5.4 for the IMAP extension, but you have 5.3 installed.

Comment: I believe the IMAP extension for PHP is actually rather old and poorly maintained; you might get a more up to date and secure implementation by downloading a PHP-based library instead.

Comment: Thanks for your replies, I have v 5.4.1 installed but still getting this error, any ideas why that could happen?

Comment: Hm, perhaps the other way around then - perhaps you used a non-standard package to get PHP 5.4, and the `php-imap` package you are trying to install is from the standard repository, so matches the normal PHP 5.3 build? In that case, you'll need to find an extension package matching your PHP build, or work out how to install the extension from source (or downgrade PHP, which I'm guessing you won't want to do).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I had the same problem. I figured out that if you list all the installed packages with:

```
yum list installed | grep php
```

You'll see:

```
php55-common.x86_64            5.5.17-2.89.amzn1            @amzn-updates/latest
php55-devel.x86_64             5.5.17-2.89.amzn1            @amzn-updates/latest
php55-gd.x86_64                5.5.17-2.89.amzn1            @amzn-updates/latest
```

It seems that all the Amazon packages are php55-xxxx rather than php-xxxx.

This worked for me via ssh. I haven't tried it via a container command.

```
sudo yum install php55-imap
```

Comment: Worked for me. Running AWS EC2 Instance with PHP55.

Comment: Still working with the current php 5.6 (php56-imap) default environment.

Comment: Hi @user1688726, are you trying this using container commands?

Answer (score 0):

Basically, in order to make it work,
you need to make sure which PHP version installed on your server
before installing new extension.

if you have php 5.6 and install other version, it still won't work for you!

to get current installed extension, use:

```
php -v
```

or

```
yum list installed | grep php
```

> 

and
then install the appropriate one:

```
sudo yum install php55-imap
```

or

```
sudo yum install php55-imap
```

or

```
any other...
```

**referrer and full guide.**
http://mdb-blog.blogspot.co.il/2015/11/how-to-install-php-imap-extension-on.html